# Multiple paths in handlers web.config

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config

How can I set multiple paths for aspNetCore in the handlers section of my web.config?  I have tried different ways, but they result in either 500 or 404 errors:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="aspNetCore" />
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="/api/*, /swagger/*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

and

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="aspNetCore" />
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="/api/*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="/sawagger/*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 3):

For `path`, it did not accept `/api/*, /swagger/*`, and you should not define the multiple handlers with the same name `aspNetCore`.

Try suggestion below:

```
<handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*/home*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    <add name="aspNetCoreapi" path="*/api/*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

For `Asp.Net Core`, you should not use `handler` and `module` to control the request, try `Middleware`.

Check [Migrate HTTP handlers and modules to ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-2.2)